# How to boost alternatives similar to top results

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I boost documents that are similar to the current top ones according to a specific field, at query time?

When someone does a search, I provide an acceptably ordered set of results, but I'd like to boost the results that share a field with the current top results.

Say I search for "Titanic" in a movie index.
I'd like movies that share DiCaprio in the "actors" field to be boosted as well, despite not having anything to do with the word "titanic"

Thank you!